# Why does format specifier "U" alter the value of DateTime?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have encountered strange behavior when using the "U" format specifier for DateTime as shown in the following passing tests:

```
DateTime tim = new DateTime(2020, 03, 29, 00, 59, 59);
  //test 1
Assert.Equal("2020-03-29 00:59:59Z", tim.ToString("u", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB")));
  //test 2
Assert.Equal("28 March 2020 23:59:59", tim.ToString("U", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB")));
  //test 3
Assert.Equal("Saturday, March 28, 2020 11:59:59 PM", tim.ToString("U", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")));
  //test 4
Assert.Equal("2020-03-29 00:59:59Z", timA.ToString("u", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")));
```

Test1 and Test4 both produce the expected string containing the date and time for display to the user; 2020-03-29 00:59:59. However, Test2 and 3 displays a string showing the time one hour earlier; 28 March 2020 23:59:59. Why does the format specifier alter the value?

The [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo?view=netcore-3.1) defines:

- "u" (universal sortable date/time; standard format string) UniversalSortableDateTimePattern, to define a result string that conforms to the ISO 8601 standard for coordinated universal time. The property is read-only.
- "U" (universal full date/time; standard format string) FullDateTimePattern, to define the overall format of the result string.

Why would a format specifier change the value? Further, why change it by one hour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you may read here [The Universal Sortable ("u") Format Specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#UniversalSortable)

> no conversion of the original DateTime value is performed

And here  [The Universal Full ("U") Format Specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#UniversalFull)

> value is automatically converted to UTC

So for test 2 and 3 assert against `tim.ToUniversalTime()`.

Comment: You are right that converting my DateTime to UTC fixes the problem. However, you didn't explain why using the "U" format specifier without doing that produces an incorrect result - i.e. displays the wrong time. I've elaborated below, but will credit you with providing the correct answer. Many thanks.

Comment: I didn't explain because I've no idea why. That problem cross my mind. And yes I think API is inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

The "U" format specifier can only be used on a DateTime of **DateTimeKind.Utc**. Therefore by changing my DateTime constructor I am able to produce passing tests with the results I expect:

```
DateTime tim = new DateTime(2020, 03, 29, 00, 59, 59, DateTimeKind.Utc);

//test 1
Assert.Equal("2020-03-29 00:59:59Z", tim.ToString("u", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB")));
//test 2
Assert.Equal("29 March 2020 00:59:59", tim.ToString("U", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB")));
//test 3
Assert.Equal("Sunday, March 29, 2020 12:59:59 AM", tim.ToString("U", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")));
//test 4
Assert.Equal("2020-03-29 00:59:59Z", tim.ToString("u", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")));
```

I will report this to Microsoft as a bug because the reasonable response to using the "U" (or "u") format specifier with a **DateTime that is not UTC** should be to throw an exception.